# Function that automatically press's a key Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ui-automation, nightmare

How would I best go about writing a function that press's a key?
(I want it to press Tab in particular)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jorg I am writing a script using `Nightmare.js` to automatically log into a website and I have come into an issue where I need the script to press tab to go into the next field of text, and I want to know how I would get that to happen.

Comment: @Jorg `Nightmare.js` allows you to write scripts that simulate a user, good for automation testing etc.

Comment: Ah ok, perhaps include that in your question. I've only seen this: https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/147

Comment: @Jorg I've actually read through that with no luck unfortunately, I've been stuck on this issue for 3 and a half hours

Comment: Can't you just set the focus on the next text field?

Comment: Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Events don't do anything, they are dispatched by user actions or programatically. Handlers respond to events by calling associated listeners/functions.

Comment: @lucas The next text field has the same class as the previous one so whenever I attempt to focus it, it will focus the first field

Comment: Ah OK. I've never heard of nightmare.js but the standard js approach would involve playing around with the indices in the collection from  getElementsByClassName or selectorAll

Comment: I use horseman.js it has keyboard events or puppeteer.js if you need something still maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is called **CHARACTER TABULATION** key, the unicode for that is `\u0009`.

I'll be using a sample keyboard test page and a very simple script as example. We can use the function `.type()` to send `\u0009` on the page. You can send any character as keyboard input and it should be working perfectly fine.

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const nightmare = new Nightmare({ show: true });
(async function() {
  await nightmare
    .goto('http://en.key-test.ru/')
    .wait(500)
    .type('body', '\u000d') // press Enter
    .type('body', '\u0009') // press Tab
    .wait(500)
    .screenshot('example.png')
    .end()
    .then(()=>{console.log('done pressing keys')})
})();
```

The result is as below. Which presses Enter and then Tab key.
[image]

Surely you won't need a function for that, right? after all you can use

```
nightmare.type('body', '\u0009')
```

anywhere and it should be what you need.